# Need guide on Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module, administrator

Its my first time to work with Joomla and I need to make a plugin that basically stores/updates a name and a City the thing is that I want this functionality only in admin panel not in the front end.

Its a bit confusing to me weather I should create a component or a module or a plugin ?

Does anyone has a good guide on how to create such functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has also been asked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/49128532/1983389

Comment: A Custom Administrator module could be created to display information in the back-end but you'll probably need to be more specific about what you want or why you want this to elicit useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to add unlimited names and cities to a database, then make a component.

If you want just two text fields, then make a module.

Plugins are more for filtering content once it has been added to the site, so do not seem applicable here.

If your template is a bespoke one, then you may also have the option to add template parameters if these fields are to be site-wide.

Joomla's [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) is as good as anything - it doesn't sound like you need anything beyond a basic hello world module to do everything you need.  Modules are far simpler than components.

If you browse around, there are a few module creators that may do what you want, but if you have the PHP knowledge, modules aren't that tricky.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "want this functionality only in admin panel not in the front end".  Generally you'd add the content in the back end and display it in the front end.  You may wish to edit your question to explain what you want to do with the information once someone has entered it, if it is not to be displayed on the front end.